# Resolve constructor parameter in a particular case

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac

I have code:

```
public class A
{
    public A(MyService myService)
    {
        // work with myService
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    public MyService(string className)
    {
        // here I want className == "A"
    }
}
```

`MyService` job depends on class name that it initialized. So i need in container config make something like

```
builder.RegisterType<MyService>()
    .AsSelf()
    .WithParameter(
        (i, c) => i.ParameterType == typeof(string) && i.Name == "className",
        (i, c) =>
        {
            // how can i find typeof(A) here on MyService building?
            return c.GetType().Name;
        });
```

or in something else place to resolve `className` veriable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom parameter that will be responsible of creating the `MyService` instance, this parameter will have access to the context where `MyService` should be created.

```
new ResolvedParameter(
    (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(MyService),
    (p, i) => new MyService(p.Member.DeclaringType.ToString())
),
```

In order not to create the `MyService` instance by yourself you can use the current context and ask Autofac to resolve it with a `NamedParameter` containing the name of the declaring type.

```
new ResolvedParameter(
    (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(MyService),
    (p, i) => i.Resolve<MyService>(
                  new NamedParameter("className", p.Member.DeclaringType.ToString())
              )
),
```

and you can use a Module to use this custom parameter in every registration

```
public class MyServiceModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += Registration_Preparing;

        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);
    }

    private void Registration_Preparing(Object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(new[] {
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(MyService),
                (p, i) => i.Resolve<MyService>(
                            new NamedParameter("className", 
                                               p.Member.DeclaringType.ToString())
                          )
            ),
        });
    }
}
```

and register your module in Autofac like this

```
builder.RegisterModule<MyServiceModule>();
```

Have in mind that the `Preparing` event is triggered only once per instance creation, if you register `MyService` with a different instance lifetime scope (singleton, etc.) the `className` value may not the expected one.